# NFC UID max read count

Tags: rfid, nfc

Documentations indicates a maximum number of read/write of 100 000 cycles for some passive NFC tags (for ex NTAG215, NTAG216, ...)

Does this limitation apply if I only read the UID without any writes / other data reads ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endurance of an EEPROM is considered regarding the writes only.
Read endurance is not described as it is so high, that there is no need to bother.

See for example:
[NXP NTAG 213/215/216](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/ntag-for-tags-labels/ntag-213-215-216-nfc-forum-type-2-tag-compliant-ic-with-144-504-888-bytes-user-memory:NTAG213_215_216)

Datasheet:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

Page 3:

> EEPROM
>
> - Data retention time of 10 years
> - Write endurance 100.000 cycles